# Creating app folder but getting TypeScript files instead of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I was following a tutorial, to set up and create an react.js + tailwindcss app, I (and the tutorial maker) used.

> npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss [app name]

the files and all are created but instead of getting javascript files (index.js etc) I get it in typescript (index.tsx).

(his)

[image]

(mine)

[image]

I read the next.js documentation and it said that if I wanted a TypeScript file I should add the --TypeScript flag to the command, which I didn't, yet still got the TypeScript files.

I followed the video and I didn't make anything different from his, so I'm wondering what did I make wrong and how to fix it.

Sorry for using any wrong tags I really don't know what I should've used.

Answer (score 0):

You did nothing wrong. The example [with-tailwindcss](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss) was recently converted to TypeScript. You can read about the decision [in the corresponding pull request](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/32808)

Comment: So is there a way to use the javascript version still? Or is it not possible anymore? Thank you for answering.

Comment: To quote the [pull request](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/32808#issuecomment-1007797562): "Yes, the example is now using TypeScript. If you would prefer not to use it, you can remove the TS configuration (it's a few files/lines)."
Basically, this should equate to deleting `tsconfig.json`, `next-env.d.ts` and going through the three files in `pages`, deleting all the types as well as type imports (the stuff behind `:` like `: NextPage` in `index.tsx` and renaming the files to `.jsx`